# How do I prepare clinical data for multivariate time series analysis using LSTM or RNNs?

Tags: regression, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, data-preprocessing

I am trying to predict the progression of disease using certain clinical data (time series data) and covariates (such as age, sex, race etc.). I am aware of the existence of mainstream machine learning and deep learning models for such prediction tasks but since clinical data are longitudinal in nature I want to leverage this and use LSTMs or RNNs (if possible) for predictions.
I have a longitudinal dataset which describes a disease progression for multiple patients (100s of patient data) each with multiple visits (~10-20 visits) at different points of time with some conclusion about the disease at each time step. My point of confusion is how to prepare this dataset for an LSTM model since most of the literature I've read on this topic shows data preparation only for one patient. I want to understand how will my model be affected if I

1. Ignore the "multiple patients model" and arrange all the data based on only time (date and time of visit).
2. Arrange data based on the patient ID first and then the date and time of visit for each patient (nested arrangement if I am clear).

Thank you.

Comment: However you proceed, you can't "ignore the multiple patients model." Correlations within each patient, leading to non-independence among observations, need to be accounted for in some way.

Comment: Yes, that's where I was most confused about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll typically need an array/tensor/"whatever else you call" it that has dimensions of patient by timepoint by variables of interest. E.g. with 1000 patients, 10 timepoints and 10 variables being measured, it would by a 1000 by 10 by 10 array (if there's just one input [or output], you can omit the last dimension). In fact, the second dimension would be the maximum number of visits you ever have to deal with. Each batch that the NN gets would be a subset of this along the first dimension (e.g. taking 128 of the 1000 patients for one batch) - of course that's the thing you'll need in the end, so if the whole array for all patients does not fit in memory, you can create a batch at a time without ever creating the full thing for all patients. You will have to decide on some reasonable thing for dealing with times, at which there's no data (e.g. is it reasonable to interpolate, have some special value for missing such as -1 when values are otherwise >=0, set to some average/median value + having a flag for missing etc.).

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense..